# Service worker doesn't work on offline mode in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, caching, service-worker

I'm new on the world of angular /Angular CLI and i begin with service worker

I try to use this tutorial :
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

And with another tutorial for create an app with angularCli who have all files for the service worker

1)  for the exemple my app name is "ServiceWorker"

2 ) make "ng build- --prod"

3 ) And after "http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/ServiceWorker"

4 )The app is launched to "http://192.168.1.14:8080" or "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

But first problem my cache is empty .... it's a problem for app who work offline lol

[Cache Storage empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98uBP.png)

And after when i activate the offline mode i have this

[error internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR4ZD.png)

Someone have a solution please ?
I dont' understand why my cache is empty all time !
I try it on my manifest.json

```
 "offline_enabled": true,
```

I try to change

```
start_url" :"/"
```

to

```
start_url": "/index.html"
```

On my url 192.168.1.14:8080 i try to add /index.html or / or nothing...it's the same

Someone have a solution please ?
I don't see anybody have this problem 
Thanks so much
Yoann

Comment: try localhost:8080 and see if it works

Comment: Thanks i will try , but localhost work all time with and without internet if i remember?

Comment: There are two ways to work wuth servive worker either it should be localhost or the url should be https protocol both of them will work offline and online

Comment: ohh thanks it's work !! i have just 4 errors on the console
GET http://localhost:8080/manifest.json 504 (Gateway Timeout)

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.

An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

but all work , so i think it's when i have modified my manisfest.json ?

thanks so much !